# How can I read GSettings values from a filesystem backup?

Tags: file-format, migration, dconf, gsettings

I have a complete filesystem backup from an old Ubuntu installation. I'd like to retrieve some data from it that was stored via [GSettings](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/en/man1/gsettings.1.html), e.g. my old GNOME Terminal color selections or the commands from custom keyboard shortcuts.

[This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/9550) says my data is stored in `~/.config/dconf/user`, which is some kind of binary database.

How can I read it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Suggested by a community member in the [GNOME IRC channel](https://wiki.gnome.org/GnomeIrcChannels):

1. Copy the old `~/.config/dconf/user` to `/tmp/dconf/user`.
2. Export the data to a human-readable format:

   ```
   XDG_CONFIG_HOME=/tmp dconf dump / > old-gsettings-data.txt
   ```
3. Optionally edit the data in a text editor and load it into the current database with [`dconf load`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/dconf).

Comment: `XDG_CONFIG_HOME=/tmp...` did not work, but `export XDG_CONFIG_HOME=/tmp...`.